# Flash and JAWS Accessibility

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, jaws-screen-reader

Currently I am trying to use JAWS screen reader to make a .swf I have created easier to those who need this sort of software.

I so far have been able to set the name and tab-indexes for two movie-clips.
I was wondering if anyone knew how to get the screen reader to read the names or descriptions of these movie-clips?

```
import flash.accessibility.AccessibilityProperties;

stop();

setupJAWS();

/////////////////////---JAWS---//////////////////////////////////////
function enable( mc:* ) {
    trace("Enabled");
    var _accessClip = mc;
    _accessClip.accessibilityProperties.silent = false;
    _accessClip.tabEnabled = true;
}

function disable( mc:* ) {
    var _accessClip = mc;
    _accessClip.accessibilityProperties.silent = true;
    _accessClip.tabEnabled = false;
}

function setupJAWS(){

trace("SETTING UP");

this.Text58.accessibilityProperties = new AccessibilityProperties();
this.Text58.accessibilityProperties.name = "TEXT1";
this.Text58.tabIndex = 2;
enable(this.Text58);

this.Text59.accessibilityProperties = new AccessibilityProperties(); 
this.Text59.accessibilityProperties.name = "TEXT2";
this.Text59.tabIndex = 3;
enable(this.Text59);

Accessibility.updateProperties();
stage.focus=Text58;
```

}

If you don't know that answer to this could you please up vote the question as I really need this answered, Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Does it work when you test SWF outside of compiler / coding environment? Does it work when SWF is embedded into an html & then viewed with **specifically** Internet Explorer?

Comment: No I have run the SWF when it is embedded into an html and it acts the same as when it is run within the compiler @VC.One

Comment: What version of IE browser do you use? It needs to be running **activeX** version of Flash Player plugin. Is `text58` an instance name for on-stage textfield? if yes, Does it work if your code references that object as `text58` instead of `this.text58`? I never used `this.` on my textFields and they were readable...

Comment: PS: The Flash Player in the compiler cannot work with JAWS. You must test in an **activeX** capable browser (meaning Internet Explorer).

Comment: Ok I'll ensure the bowser i am using is activeX capable when i have a spare moment and also play around with removing the 'this' keyword thank you for all your help. @VC.One